# my script isn't reformatting my csv with all the data im getting just headers\\python 3

Tags: python, csv

my script isn't reformatting my csv with all the data just headers. when i ran my code it just gave me the headers and the data goes missing im not sure why?, i want to make the output csv to have my requested headers with the data underneath

```
import csv
with open('motherwell.csv','r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

with open('stats.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    fieldnames = ['id','name','product','temperature','density','timestamp','water']

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for line in csv_reader:
        del line['shortname','state','shape','pos_x','pos_y','datum',',max_work','min_work','offset_bottom','offset_volume','offset_level','roof_density','roof_weight','roof_start','roof_end','shell_insulated','shell_cte','shell_temperature','dimension_a','dimension_b','dimension_c','dimension_d','knee_forth','knee_third','knee_second','knee_first','suction_forth,','suction_third','suction_second','suction_first','rundown_forth','rundown_third','rundown_second','rundown_first','suction_low_forth','suction_low_third','suction_low_second','suction_low_first','rundown_low_forth','rundown_low_third','rundown_low_second','rundown_low_first','sll','slu','svl','suv','swlv','swuv','swll','swul','volume','innage','flow','pressure','maximum_volume',]
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

here is the csv with the data: also a link to get the csv
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qdcl2lrrqj6sttb/AABo_AMGzFqetgRne_7XTPy7a?dl=0

> "{'id': 1, 'name': '1001A', 'shortname': 'A', 'product': '14', 'state': 'Y', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '72', 'pos_y': '34', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0.0, 'slu': 22000.0, 'svl': 0.0, 'suv': 288901000000.0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0.0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0.0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:48'}","{'id': 2, 'name': '1001B', 'shortname': 'B', 'product': '14', 'state': 'Y', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '62', 'pos_y': '54', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0.0, 'slu': 22000.0, 'svl': 0.0, 'suv': 288901000000.0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0.0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:48'}","{'id': 3, 'name': '1001C', 'shortname': 'C', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '80', 'pos_y': '36', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:48'}","{'id': 4, 'name': '1001D', 'shortname': 'D', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '91', 'pos_y': '56', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:48'}","{'id': 5, 'name': '1001E', 'shortname': 'E', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '47', 'pos_y': '24', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:48'}","{'id': 6, 'name': '1001F', 'shortname': 'F', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '62', 'pos_y': '18', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:49'}","{'id': 7, 'name': '1001G', 'shortname': 'G', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'cylinder', 'pos_x': '69', 'pos_y': '14', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:49'}","{'id': 8, 'name': '1001H', 'shortname': 'H', 'product': '14', 'state': 'N', 'shape': 'open-floating-roof', 'pos_x': '48', 'pos_y': '54', 'datum': '0', 'max_work': '21000', 'min_work': '0', 'offset_bottom': '0', 'offset_volume': '0', 'offset_level': '0', 'roof_density': '0', 'roof_weight': '0', 'roof_start': '0', 'roof_end': '0', 'shell_insulated': 'N', 'shell_cte': '0', 'shell_temperature': '0', 'shell_capacity': '0', 'shell_molecular': '0', 'shell_pressure': '0', 'shell_gtemp': '0', 'dimension_a': 22000, 'dimension_b': 76000, 'dimension_c': 0, 'dimension_d': 0, 'knee_forth': 100.0, 'knee_third': 70.0, 'knee_second': 30.0, 'knee_first': 0.0, 'suction_forth': 0.0, 'suction_third': 0.0, 'suction_second': 0.0, 'suction_first': 0.0, 'rundown_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_third': 0.0, 'rundown_second': 0.0, 'rundown_first': 0.0, 'suction_low_forth': 0.0, 'suction_low_third': 0.0, 'suction_low_second': 0.0, 'suction_low_first': 0.0, 'rundown_low_forth': 0.0, 'rundown_low_third': 0.0, 'rundown_low_second': 0.0, 'rundown_low_first': 0.0, 'sll': 0, 'slu': 0, 'svl': 0, 'suv': 0, 'swlv': 0, 'swuv': 0, 'swll': 0, 'swul': 0, 'volume': 0, 'innage': 0, 'flow': 0, 'water': 0, 'density': 700, 'pressure': 0, 'temperature': 0, 'maximum_volume': 288901000000.0, 'timestamp': '2017-12-14 09:24:49'}"

Comment: This is not a csv.

Comment: what do you mean? both files format as csv

Comment: I mean that neither what you posted above nor the file you linked to are proper csv files. Well technically yes - if you consider that one single line composed of (what looks like) json strings enclosed by quotes and separated by commas is a proper csv...

Comment: is there a way i can make them into real csv files then?

Comment: Yes - but you will have to parse it by yourself. Accidentally the csv reader still makes a proper job of splitting this single long line in a list of serialized dicts. Then you can use `ast.literal_eval()` on each of those serialized dicts to turn them into proper python dicts, and then you can use a DictWriter to write them back as proper csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not a proper csv. Well, technically you could consider it as such since there are indeed things enclosed on quotes and separated by commas, but it's all on one single line and those "things" really looks like serialized python dicts (first thought this was json but json.loads() fails on it, while ast.literal_eval() do the job).

Since there's only one line, and you don't pass any fieldnames to `csv.DictReader`, it tries to use the first line as headers, so each of those json-like objects is considered like a fieldname. Then, since the one and only line has been consumed, the iteration stops, which is why you don't have any data in the result file.

You can find this out by yourself:

```
f = open("motherwell.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
print(reader.fieldnames)
try:
    row = reader.next()
    print(row)
except StopIteration:
    print("nothing else here, dude")
```

Actually, a proper csv file would look something like (header and first rows):

```
 swlv,shell_cte,maximum_volume,offset_bottom,datum,suction_second,swuv,shell_temperature,shape,swul,knee_second,roof_end,suction_low_third,swll,knee_forth,suction_forth,id,dimension_b,roof_start,dimension_a,temperature,dimension_d,rundown_low_second,water,innage,suction_low_first,state,timestamp,shortname,roof_weight,shell_capacity,svl,product,rundown_forth,dimension_c,knee_first,suv,max_work,offset_volume,rundown_third,pressure,roof_density,rundown_low_forth,suction_first,rundown_second,volume,pos_x,pos_y,name,rundown_low_first,shell_gtemp,density,flow,shell_pressure,shell_molecular,shell_insulated,sll,knee_third,offset_level,suction_low_forth,min_work,suction_third,rundown_low_third,rundown_first,suction_low_second,slu
0,0,2.88901e+11,0,0,0.0,0,0,cylinder,0,30.0,0,0.0,0,100.0,0.0,1,76000,0,22000,0.0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,Y,2017-12-14 09:24:48,A,0,0,0.0,14,0.0,0,0.0,2.88901e+11,21000,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,72,34,1001A,0.0,0,700,0,0,0,N,0.0,70.0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,22000.0
0,0,2.88901e+11,0,0,0.0,0,0,cylinder,0,30.0,0,0.0,0,100.0,0.0,2,76000,0,22000,0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,Y,2017-12-14 09:24:48,B,0,0,0.0,14,0.0,0,0.0,2.88901e+11,21000,0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,62,54,1001B,0.0,0,700,0,0,0,N,0.0,70.0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,22000.0
```

So to make a long story short: this is not a proper csv file but a concatenation of serialized Python dicts, and so you cannot hope to correctly parse this with a csv parser.

Comment: ok thank you very much ill have to find a way of getting the motherwell.csv out of the other script without it messing the csv file up

Answer (score -1):

You need to change with open('stats.csv', 'w') as new_file: this row and only change "w"(write) to "a"(append) model. Hope this will help.

Comment: so basically it will look like with open('stats.csv', 'a') as new_file:

Comment: And how is this supposed to solve the problem exactly ? The OP doesn't close the output file between writing the headers and the rows...

Comment: as i understood it writes only one row,

Comment: "as i understood it writes only one row" => yes, and ? The file is not closed during the write operations.

Comment: the file is closed

Comment: try to do like csv_reader = csv.DictReader(open(“filename”, “mode”))

Comment: so i can get the motherwell csv file to be copied

Comment: @DLP your problem has nothing to do with how the file is opened actually.